# What's the difference between the following two ways for model loading in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training a model with `tf.layers.batch_normalization` API. And after training, I need to load the trained model to do prediction on new data. There are two ways to load the weights, as follows:

(1):

```
saver1 = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), max_to_keep=10)
saver1.restore(sess, '{}'.format(args.restore_ckpt))
```

(2):

```
saver2 = tf.train.import_meta_graph('{}.meta'.format(args.restore_ckpt))
saver2.restore(sess, '{}'.format(args.restore_ckpt))
```

I found (1) can generate high prediction accuracy (say, `97%`), but (2) has a much lower accuracy (say, `59%`). Does this mean the (2) didn't load the weights for the batch normalization layers correctly? Looking forward to your comments!

**UPDATED:**

I found with the model loaded by (1) have the same prediction accuracy no matter what the test batch_size is. I tried the batch size with 1 and 16, both results have 97% of accuracy.

It seems with the weights loaded by (2), I need to add the following code:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        train_op = optimizer_op.minimize(loss_total_op, global_step=global_step)
```

Then it would generate a high accuracy `97%`. Maybe I wrongly understood the batch normalization.